# How to get the page load time of a windows app using sikulix and java?

Tags: java, sikuli

I'm trying to automate windows app using sikuli with eclipse IDE and want to get the time for windows app loading time

In skulix there's wait(pattern, FOREVER) function which system waits until image loads but i Can't find matching function for the same in eclipse/ java

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Constants class - Forever?
[Constants](http://doc.sikuli.org/javadoc/org/sikuli/script/Constants.html#FOREVER)

wait(Constants.FOREVER);